# Returning different value depending on div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to write one function that returns a string depending on a div clicked.

```
<div id="footer">
<table>
    <tr>
<td><div id="selectpeg1" onclick="selectPeg()"></div></td>
<td><div id="selectpeg2" onclick="selectPeg()"></div></td>
<td><div id="selectpeg3" onclick="selectPeg()"></div></td>
<td><div id="selectpeg4" onclick="selectPeg()"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The selectPeg() function has to either return a string or a "background" parameter located in the CSS file (also as a string). So, if I click on a first peg, the function can return "blue", if I click the second peg the function returns "red" and so on...

CSS:

```
#selectpeg1 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: yellow;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 30px;
border-style: solid;
```

}

Comment: returns to where? what shall happen with the return value? shall the returned value be logged to the console? Or should a global variable receive the returned value? Alternatively, the return value might be processed by a callback. So what do you want to do with the value the function returns?

Comment: I just need a return function. Then, I'll change another div's colour depending on a div clicked in this footer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use only javascript and not jquery then you need to make the following change.

1. Pass this in the function call in the html:

   onclick="selectPeg(this)"
2. In the java script function add a function argument:

   function selectPeg(element)

than you can easily get data from the element variable.

```
function selectPeg(element) {

    var id = element.id
    var backgroud = element.style.background
    var color = element.style.color

    // do anything you want to do
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is very useful, but I added console log and it only seems to print the value of the id. console.log(color) and console.log(background) output an empty verse in the console

Comment: if element.style isn't working then you can try `var computedstyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);` to get all the style applied to the element. Then just do computedstyle.background and computedstyle,color.

Comment: how do I get a background color as a string out of this? 
It returns a list with numbered properties of style

Comment: you can do computedstyle.background

Comment: visit this link for more detail https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: gamescript.js:13rgb(0, 0, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box - that's the output. I need a simple string as "blue", etc. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Example 1: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/nLfvrey7/

You can use 'data' attributes... they can be anything... `data-bananas='2'` or anything you want.

```
<ul class="thing-list">
  <li class="thing" data-info='one'>one</li>
  <li class="thing" data-info='two'>two</li>
  <li class="thing" data-info='three'>three</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript.. using some jQuery

```
var $thing = $('.thing'); // cache node you'll use early

function getInfo(target) { // function that gets info from a given target
  var info = $(target).data('info'); // check target for data-info
  alert(info); // do something with that info
}

$thing.on('click', function() { // attach click event listener
  getInfo(this); // run function where the target is 'this' - the thing that got clicked...
});
```

You can certainly write this without jQuery:  http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

But the key here is conceptual - so, I'm just writing what is fastest and most readable. In most cases - trying to skip jQuery is just the current pack mentality and not really with much reason in many cases.

here is a full example with the colors changing for fun:

Example 2: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dm4pofuz/

Comment: Yes. jQuery is just a library of JavaScript methods that make these easier and more readable and deals with cross-browser pains. Anything that you can do with jQuery can be written with standard JavaScript - it's just more work and the API isn't as pleasurable to work with.

Comment: yea, but thats not my idea mate. these are the requirements for my projects

Comment: @szubansky why do you tag your question with `jquery` then?

Comment: Also - now that the concept is outlined... you can go learn how to get data-attributes without jQuery - or how to query for selectors in a non-jquery way. The question is answered. I'm not going to write it out in a way you can just copy and paste into the project. Here is a course you can take that is all Vanilla JS: https://javascript30.com/  Good Luck!  : )

Comment: I got it sheriff, ty ;)

Answer (score 1):

Combining [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) provides for a clean solution:

```js
function onSelectorClick(event) {
  console.log(this.dataset.color); // TODO: do something with color
}

document.querySelectorAll(".selector").forEach(element => {
  element.style.setProperty("--color", element.dataset.color);
  element.addEventListener("click", onSelectorClick);
});
```

```css
.selector {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: var(--color, white);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="selector" data-color="red"></div></td>
    <td><div class="selector" data-color="blue"></div></td>
    <td><div class="selector" data-color="green"></div></td>
    <td><div class="selector" data-color="yellow"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```